# Копирование страницы из pdf файла в word файл

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word

Необходимо скопировать первую страницу pdf файла в word файл(doc,docx) с помощью ЯП Java.

Comment: пожалуйста, не пишите название языка в заголовке вопроса для этого есть метки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150205/5330439)

```
//Create the word document
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

// Open the pdf file
String pdf = "myfile.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

// Read the PDF page by page
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(i, new         SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
// Extract the text
String text=strategy.getResultantText();
// Create a new paragraph in the word document, adding the extracted text
XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
run.setText(text);
// Adding a page break
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
}
 // Write the word document
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.docx");
 doc.write(out);
 // Close all open files
 out.close();
 reader.close();
```

В [помощь](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&newwindow=1&hl=ru&site=webhp&source=hp&q=pdftoword+java&oq=pdftoword+java&gs_l=hp.3..0i13k1l2j0i22i30k1l5j0i13i5i30k1l3.1566.12857.0.16534.17.12.3.0.0.0.337.1903.0j9j1j1.11.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..3.13.1578.0..0j0i131k1j0i10i1k1j0i10k1j0i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i13i10k1.lM0_X2A2QRI)

Comment: Это хороший и скорее всего рабочий метод, но проблема в том что:  PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);данного класса нет в бесплатной версии itext7 что делать?